# xcode not showing some files

Tags: xcode, git, github

Me and my team are using git for a project and we are all new to it. Anyway, after adding some class files to the project (objective C project) and making commits, when another person clones the project, Xcode doesn't show the added files. I saw  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036462/xcode-does-not-pick-up-new-class-files-in-svn)
and I understand that we should have been commiting the .xcodeproj file all along. Now since the .xcodeproj file in the repository is the original file without the changes from everyone, how do I change my copy so that Xcode shows the files? They can be seen in Finder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drag the as-yet-unseen files into the "project navigator", that is, the tree of files you see on the left (that you wish would have your files).

Answer (score -1):

Try this, it worked for me.

1. Open the project in Xcode
2. Open the project in Finder
3. Double click on the files, they will automatically show up in the project navigator inside Xcode.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. I work in between two computers. The reason why I could not see the files in Xcode was because before committing the latest update I forgot to add the new files:

```
git add .
```

And then

```
git commit -m "Your message"
```

Hope this helps someone out there :)